# Save json to ftp dir

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a dir already exists on a ftp server, if it exists then it should only create and save a json file to this dir and `return true`, incase it does not exist, then it should create the dir first and save the json file to  the dir and also `return true` otherwise it should `return false`.

my code currently looks like the following:

```
<?php

    // Function to create the outfit xml file
    function create_outfit_json(){
        if (!file_exists('../user/' . $this->Username)) {
            mkdir('../user/' . $this->username, 0777, true);

            $json['outfits'] = [];
            $json['outfits']['0'] = [
                'outfit'   => [
                    'url' => 'placeholder',
                    'default' => 1,
                    'name' => 'New outfit',
                    'c' => '#bb9977',
                    'mood' => 3,
                    'species' => 'male'
                ]
            ];

            $fp = fopen('../user/' . $this->Username . '/outfits.json', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
            fclose($fp);

            return true;
        }else if(file_exists('../user/' . $this->Username)){
            $json['outfits'] = [];
            $json['outfits']['0'] = [
                'outfit'   => [
                    'url' => 'placeholder',
                    'default' => 1,
                    'name' => 'New outfit',
                    'c' => '#bb9977',
                    'mood' => 3,
                    'species' => 'male'
                ]
            ];

            $fp = fopen('../user/' . $this->Username . '/outfits.json', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
            fclose($fp);

            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

?>
```

Is there a way to make this code look more clean and short?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and yes, theres a lot to improve.

Comment: Your if and ifelse does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Neat No he has a mkdir if it doesnt exist on the very beginning :P

Comment: The only difference in the if and else if is the following: mkdir('../user/' . $this->username, 0777, true); thats why i asked if theres a better way to realize this

Comment: @d4ne https://bpaste.net/show/f456883c424e

Comment: @d4ne Btw are you sure that this is correct: you have `$this->Username` and `$this->username`

Comment: Tahnks for the info and your right was a typo :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // Function to create the outfit xml file
    function create_outfit_json(){
        if (!file_exists('../user/' . $this->Username)) {
            mkdir('../user/' . $this->Username, 0777, true);
        }

            $json['outfits']['0'] = [
                'outfit'   => [
                    'url' => 'placeholder',
                    'default' => 1,
                    'name' => 'New outfit',
                    'c' => '#bb9977',
                    'mood' => 3,
                    'species' => 'male'
                ]
            ];

            $fp = fopen('../user/' . $this->Username . '/outfits.json', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

?>
```

You dont need the redundant code - just wrap the `mkdir` in one if.

Comment: `$json['outfits'] = [];` is unnecessary, and you left out the returns

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments, always write code with reuse ability,

```
    // Seperate all data and saving
    function create_outfit_json(){
        $json['outfits'] = [];
        $json['outfits']['0'] = [
            'outfit'   => [
                'url' => 'placeholder',
                'default' => 1,
                'name' => 'New outfit',
                'c' => '#bb9977',
                'mood' => 3,
                'species' => 'male'
            ]
        ];
        return $this->saveToDirectory(json_encode($json), 'outfits.json');
    }

    // passing data and filename will give you flexibility 
    function saveToDirectory($data, $filename){
        if (!file_exists('../user/' . $this->Username)) {
            mkdir('../user/' . $this->username, 0777, true);
        }
        // rather than opening connection let php do it for you
        return file_put_contents('../user/'.$this->Username.'/'.$filename, $data);
    }
```